# Файлы установки Windows не запускаются после перезагрузки

Tags: windows, windows-xp, radeon

Устанавливаю Windows XP на ноутбук Toshiba Satellite. Ноутбук старый, изначально на нем стояла Vista. Потом кто-то поставил Windows 7. Но Windows 7 драйверов для видеокарты при установке видимо не нашлось, поэтому все выглядело мягко говоря страшно. Драйверов win7 на видекарту (ATI Radeon) не нашлось и на официальном сайте. Поэтому решил поставить Windows XP. Объединил разделы через Acronis, так как там в общем всего 60 Гб. Раздел автоматически сделался активным и основным. Еще раз отформатировал диск. Начал установку XP. Копирование файлов установки прошло нормально. Дальше ноут пошел на перезагрузку. После перезагрузки черный экран и мигающий курсор в левом верхнем углу. Почему не запускается установка не понятно. Может кто сталкивался с таким.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это от недостатка драйверов в дистрибутиве ХР.

Проблема может быть решена несколькими способами:

1. Вернуть назад Висту (но где её сейчас найдёшь, и кому она нафиг нужна?)
2. Попробовать поставить Windows7, с драйверами от Висты (процентов на 95 подходят)
3. Поставить пиратскую сборку ХР, со всеми навороченными драйверами (чего не советую, но рассматриваю как способ)
4. И наконец - самое сложное. Через [NLite](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLite) собрать самому под свой ноутбук дистрибутив ХР со всеми необходимыми драйверами. Если драйверов нет у Тошибы, то их можно найти у изготовителя чипсета, которого я не знаю, потому что модель ноутбука вы не указали.

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема решилась другим способом. Загрузился с LiveCD и произвел низкоуровневое форматирование диска с помощью Low Level Format Tool. После этого создал заново раздел,  отформатировал во время установки и все пошло как надо.

Comment: А в BIOS Setup режим AHCI случайно не отключали? Если отключили, то это и было решением проблемы, и можно было обойтись без низкоуровнего форматирования. Просто, не во всех Satellite эта опция есть, а конкретно модель я не знал.